# Determining exact distance travelled

Tags: core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

What is wrong here? I am trying to get total distance travelled but when I start driving back to the point I started my value goes down? What needs to be fixed. Thank you.

```
    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    if (startLocation == nil)
        self.startLocation = newLocation; //if this is the first update colocation called startlocation = new location

    CLLocationDistance distanceBetween = [newLocation
                                          distanceFromLocation:startLocation]; //here is my problem I think

    NSString *tripString = [[NSString alloc]       //convert to string
                            initWithFormat:@"%f",
                            distanceBetween];
    distance.text = tripString; //update my distance label called distance


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this approach:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    if (startLocation == nil)
    {
        self.totalDistanceBetween = 0; // declare this variable
        self.startLocation = newLocation;
    }
    CLLocationDistance distanceBetween = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:startLocation ];
    startLocation = newLocation;
    self.totalDistanceBetween += distanceBetween; // declare this variable
    NSString *tripString = [[NSString alloc]       //convert to string
                            initWithFormat:@"%f",
                            self.totalDistanceBetween];
    distance.text = tripString; //update my distance label called distance
}
```

Comment: what variable type should totaldistancebetween be?

Comment: @Rookie CLLocationDistance or double

Comment: @Rookie it should be declared as member of this class, or as static variable, but not within function

Comment: Alright what happens is it jumps large sums(hundreds or thousands) but after 15 seconds or so it starts updating correctly(assuming the value is updating in meters). Im not familiar with core location but what maybe seems to be going on is a strong connection isnt established from the start and takes a while. For testing purposes I have my CLLocationManager started when the view loads. If I am correct how do I confirm a good connection is made before the updating begins. Or is it something else? Thanks for your help!

Comment: read about distanceFilter https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/distanceFilter looks like it solve problem with initial positioning